# Get different URL-image when I use Wi-Fi or gprs

Tags: android, image, caching, picasso, android-glide

When I update my image on server, if I use gprs the application show old image but it is OK when I use Wi-Fi

My code is:

```
Picasso.get()
            .load(urldisplay)
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE,NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
            .into(imageView);
```

Comment: GPRS is extremely slow, like dialup slow. Picasso is probably timing out and using a cached image.

Comment: I use 4G and picasso show image immediately

Comment: Exactly my point. GPRS is too slow to load images.

Answer (score 0):

GPRS is too slow, the max speed is 115kpbs while it usually averages about 35kpbs. What could be happening is that the request is timing out and Picasso is using a cached version of it.

Comment: Here, memoryPolicy and networkPolicy both have been defined to not use cache at all. So, Picasso won't do anything if it has timed out. No change will happen to imageview in such case. If it was showing an image, it will continue to show that only.

Comment: when i request for first time it works fine but if i change image picasso load old image.its confusing and not related to timeout

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.just append this at the end of url.

```
"?=" + System.currentTimeMillis();
```